# How to use substring to get my data in Java?

Tags: java, substring

My string is like this:

```
<Contestants Count = "4"><Contestant Name="EBI">7</Contestant><Contestant Name="ATILIA">13</Contestant><Contestant Name="HAFIZ">10</Contestant><Contestant Name="ESTRANGED">9</Contestant></Contestants>
```

I need to take out number according to name. For example, I need to know what is the number of "ATILIA", the result should be 13.

Comment: If your string is really as simple as in your example, you could use a regex like `yourString.replaceFirst(".*?Name=\"ATILIA\">(\\d+)<.*", "$1")`. But you will be more safe with an xml parsing lib and xpath like @Lukas Eder suggests.

Comment: what regex ? this is just xml

Comment: @kommradHomer: I did not suggest it as the preferred way. Just saying if you know what kind of string you are dealing with and a simple one-liner could do, why bother using any xml library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use java's built in XML classes. I wrote you a little example; a class, Main, with a method getNumber which throws an exception if the given name wasn't found.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
                getNumber(
                        "<Contestants Count = \"4\">" +
                        "<Contestant Name=\"EBI\">7</Contestant>" +
                        "<Contestant Name=\"ATILIA\">13</Contestant>" +
                        "<Contestant Name=\"HAFIZ\">10</Contestant>" +
                        "<Contestant Name=\"ESTRANGED\">9</Contestant>" +
            "</Contestants>", "ATILIA"));
    }

    static int getNumber(String xml, String name) throws Exception {
        int number = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inputSourse = new InputSource();
        inputSourse.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSourse);
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Contestant");
        for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
            if("ATILIA".equals(element.getAttribute("Name"))) {
                number = Integer.parseInt(element.getTextContent());
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            throw new Exception("Name not found.");
        return number;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will probably have to read up on XML and XPath in one way or the other. A simple way to access that contestant would be to use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), a library I wrote for simple jquery-like interaction with XML in Java. With jOOX, you'd write:

```
// import the "$() and attr()" operators in your Java class
import static org.joox.JOOX.*;

// With CSS selector syntax, just as in jquery:
String result = $(xmlstring).find("Contestant[Name='ATILIA']").text();

// With XPath
String result = $(xmlstring).xpath("//Contestant[@Name='ATILIA']").text();

// With the jOOX API
String result = $(xmlstring).find("Contestant")
                            .filter(attr("Name", "ATILIA"))
                            .text();
```

Of course, you have many other options. Another one would be to parse the XML without any third-party libraries, as such:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlstring)));

NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Contestant");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

  if ("ATILIA".equals(element.getAttribute("Name"))) {
    // Found it!
    System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
  }
}
```

What I recommend you *do not do* is treat XML as plain strings and start parsing / reading it with your own substring methods. There are many things that can go wrong with that technique!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the index of the name...

```
int nameIndex = line.indexOf(name);
```

Then you need to find the less than and greater than after the name...

```
int greaterThan = line.indexOf(">",nameIndex);
int lessThan = line.indexOf("<",greaterThan);
```

Then finally get the substring between them...

```
String substring = line.substring(greaterThan+1,lessThan);
```

If you need to convert the value to a number...

```
int substringNumber = Integer.parseInt(substring);
```

All this is assuming you don't want to use an XML parser to do it - this is just simple String manipulations

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend that someone who's not aware of simple Java `String` manipulation functions, should start parsing XML manually... They will be quite frustrated by the number of mistakes they can make :-)

Comment: I was only offering this as an answer because the tags and question header mentioned substring, so thought that they were probably asking for substring-specific method use rather than XML parsing. I do totally agree though, there is a lot of potential for errors.

Answer (score 0):

just parse your XML and  put your values in a HashMap keyed by the name attributes of  Contestant elements

suggestion for parsing XML [Xom](http://www.xom.nu/)

Comment: ah no. all my intention with this answer was just to give a voice to the fact that he should use XML parsing